# preg_match doesn't work in a script php but work online

Tags: php, regex

I need to get all occurrence of a string so I did a regex which it's work on http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html but when I did this regex in a script php it's doesn't work, I don't know why.

This is the regex which I used on http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html :

```
'input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"invitation\\" value=\\"(\w+)\\"'
```

This is the line which I used in my script php (I just add delimiters '/'):

```
 preg_match('/input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"invitation\\" value=\\"(\w+)\\"/', $output, $regs);
```

And the string :

```
 {"data": {}, "actions": [["html", "\u003cdiv id=\"invites-container\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"invitation-table-container\"\u003e\u003ctable class=\"invitation-table\"\u003e\u003ctr class=\"invitation-row\" data-invite-id=\"351628621\"\u003e\u003ctd class=\"invitation-icon\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/icon_spacer-vflN3BYt2.gif\" class=\"s_web_folder_user_32 sprite_web sprite invitation-icon\" /\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-header\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-folder-name\"\u003etest\u003c/span\u003e, invited by florian dell'aiera\u003c/span\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-details\"\u003e4 hrs ago\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"sf-invite-button-container\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"sf-invite-action\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"ajax-loading-indicator\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/ajax-loading-small-vfl3Wt7C_.gif\" /\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cform action=\"/inbox_accept\" novalidate=\"novalidate\" onsubmit=\"return Sharing.register_accept(this);\" method=\"post\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"_subject_uid\" value=\"64927232\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351628621\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"no_redirect\" value=\"True\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"submit\" class=\"freshbutton-blue\" value=\"Accept\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e \u003cform action=\"/inbox_decline_ajax\" novalidate=\"novalidate\" method=\"post\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"_subject_uid\" value=\"64927232\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351628621\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"delete_not_on_error\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" onclick=\"Sharing.register_decline(this, 351628621);\" value=\"Decline\" class=\"freshbutton\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e\u003cform novalidate=\"novalidate\" method=\"post\" class=\"view-folder-form\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" class=\"freshbutton view-folder-button\" value=\"View folder\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr class=\"invitation-row\" data-invite-id=\"351017268\"\u003e\u003ctd class=\"invitation-icon\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/icon_spacer-vflN3BYt2.gif\" class=\"s_web_folder_user_32 sprite_web sprite invitation-icon\" /\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-header\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-folder-name\"\u003e204canards-20\u2026ll-a_f\u003c/span\u003e, invited by florian dell'aiera\u003c/span\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-details\"\u003e23/4/2014 10:51 AM\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"sf-invite-button-container\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"sf-invite-action\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"ajax-loading-indicator\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/ajax-loading-small-vfl3Wt7C_.gif\" /\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cform action=\"/inbox_accept\" novalidate=\"novalidate\" onsubmit=\"return Sharing.register_accept(this);\" method=\"post\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"_subject_uid\" value=\"64927232\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351017268\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"no_redirect\" value=\"True\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"submit\" class=\"freshbutton-blue\" value=\"Accept\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e \u003cform action=\"/inbox_decline_ajax\" novalidate=\"novalidate\" method=\"post\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"_subject_uid\" value=\"64927232\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351017268\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"delete_not_on_error\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" onclick=\"Sharing.register_decline(this, 351017268);\" value=\"Decline\" class=\"freshbutton\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e\u003cform novalidate=\"novalidate\" method=\"post\" class=\"view-folder-form\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" class=\"freshbutton view-folder-button\" value=\"View folder\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"db-modal-buttons\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"ajax-loading-indicator\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/ajax-loading-small-vfl3Wt7C_.gif\" /\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" class=\"cancel-button freshbutton-silver\" value=\"Close\" /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cscript\u003erequire.config({\"paths\": {}}); requirejs([], function() { // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3\n\n$j('#invites-container').find('.cancel-button').on('click', function() {\n  return DBModalStack.pop();\n});\n });\u003c/script\u003e", ".dynamic-content"]]}
```

If someone have an idea why it's doesn't work on php.

thanks advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another try: **three** backslashes.

The following code works for me:

```
$output = 'div id=\"invites-container\"';

$regs = array();

$x = preg_match('/div id=\\\"invites-container\\\"/', $output, $regs);

print_r($regs);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => div id=\"invites-container\"
)
```

That was *way* harder than it needed to be :-)

Comment: If I'm looking at his input string properly, though, he has escaped quotes, so he needs to match the literal backslashes.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw you're right, I overlooked that. Back to the drawing board :-)

Comment: I tried but it's doesn't work too, i put double escaping because string search it's: ".... \u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351017268\ ...." so i said to myself maybe pregmatch doesn't match because of this  that's why i add double escaping

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
preg_match('/input type=\\\\"hidden\\\\" name=\\\\"invitation\\\\" value=\\\\"(\w+)\\\\"/', $output)
```

http://regex101.com/r/jE0bZ6

**NOTE:** On regex101 it matches with 3 backslashes only.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work too :/ it's weird I don't understand why it doesn't work on my script php

Answer (score 0):

An other way without regex (since you are dealing with json and html):

```
$json = <<<'EOD'
 {"data": {}, "actions": [["html", "\u003cdiv id=\"invites-container\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"invitation-table-container\"\u003e\u003ctable class=\"invitation-table\"\u003e\u003ctr class=\"invitation-row\" data-invite-id=\"351628621\"\u003e\u003ctd class=\"invitation-icon\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/icon_spacer-vflN3BYt2.gif\" class=\"s_web_folder_user_32 sprite_web sprite invitation-icon\" /\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-header\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-folder-name\"\u003etest\u003c/span\u003e, invited by florian dell'aiera\u003c/span\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-details\"\u003e4 hrs ago\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"sf-invite-button-container\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"sf-invite-action\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"ajax-loading-indicator\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/ajax-loading-small-vfl3Wt7C_.gif\" /\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cform action=\"/inbox_accept\" novalidate=\"novalidate\" onsubmit=\"return Sharing.register_accept(this);\" method=\"post\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"_subject_uid\" value=\"64927232\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351628621\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"no_redirect\" value=\"True\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"submit\" class=\"freshbutton-blue\" value=\"Accept\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e \u003cform action=\"/inbox_decline_ajax\" novalidate=\"novalidate\" method=\"post\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"_subject_uid\" value=\"64927232\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351628621\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"delete_not_on_error\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" onclick=\"Sharing.register_decline(this, 351628621);\" value=\"Decline\" class=\"freshbutton\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e\u003cform novalidate=\"novalidate\" method=\"post\" class=\"view-folder-form\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" class=\"freshbutton view-folder-button\" value=\"View folder\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr class=\"invitation-row\" data-invite-id=\"351017268\"\u003e\u003ctd class=\"invitation-icon\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/icon_spacer-vflN3BYt2.gif\" class=\"s_web_folder_user_32 sprite_web sprite invitation-icon\" /\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-header\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-folder-name\"\u003e204canards-20\u2026ll-a_f\u003c/span\u003e, invited by florian dell'aiera\u003c/span\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e\u003cspan class=\"invitation-details\"\u003e23/4/2014 10:51 AM\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd class=\"sf-invite-button-container\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"sf-invite-action\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"ajax-loading-indicator\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/ajax-loading-small-vfl3Wt7C_.gif\" /\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cform action=\"/inbox_accept\" novalidate=\"novalidate\" onsubmit=\"return Sharing.register_accept(this);\" method=\"post\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"_subject_uid\" value=\"64927232\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351017268\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"no_redirect\" value=\"True\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"submit\" class=\"freshbutton-blue\" value=\"Accept\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e \u003cform action=\"/inbox_decline_ajax\" novalidate=\"novalidate\" method=\"post\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"_subject_uid\" value=\"64927232\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"invitation\" value=\"351017268\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"delete_not_on_error\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" onclick=\"Sharing.register_decline(this, 351017268);\" value=\"Decline\" class=\"freshbutton\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e\u003cform novalidate=\"novalidate\" method=\"post\" class=\"view-folder-form\"\u003e\u003cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"t\" value=\"QieCCwKi5xdK172qdmIOddoI\" /\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" class=\"freshbutton view-folder-button\" value=\"View folder\" /\u003e\u003c/form\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"db-modal-buttons\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"ajax-loading-indicator\"\u003e\u003cimg src=\"https://dt8kf6553cww8.cloudfront.net/static/images/icons/ajax-loading-small-vfl3Wt7C_.gif\" /\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cinput type=\"button\" class=\"cancel-button freshbutton-silver\" value=\"Close\" /\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cscript\u003erequire.config({\"paths\": {}}); requirejs([], function() { // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3\n\n$j('#invites-container').find('.cancel-button').on('click', function() {\n  return DBModalStack.pop();\n});\n });\u003c/script\u003e", ".dynamic-content"]]}
EOD;

$html = json_decode($json)->actions[0][1];

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

foreach($inputs as $input) {
    if ($input->getAttribute('type') == 'hidden' && $input->getAttribute('name') == 'invitation')
        echo $input->getAttribute('value'). "\n";
}
```

Comment: I have a unexpected T_SL error when I do this , I will search why and I come to you as soon as I have news

Comment: @user3573358: You must check that `EOD;` is a the start of the line and that there are no hidden white characters after (or before).

Comment: thanks for your help, i discover an other way but i take the solution of Krypten :)